# Improving Cronbach Alpha after removing highly correlated questions

Tags: correlation, cronbachs-alpha, item-analysis

I am currently conducing a cronbach alpha analysis on some questionnaire data and the cronbach scores are low. I have created a correlation matrix to see which items are highly correlated and which are low.

I am getting confused as to which numbers I should be looking at for removing - for example should I be looking at the numbers nearest to 0 and then removing them to improve the score or should I be focusing on probability scores?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Item analysis in most softwares will tell you about the Cronbach's $\alpha$ if an item is deleted. But without more information, it is hard to answer your question (How many items do you have? Are you developing a new scale? etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your message, so I have additionally ran the item total command to see improvements via particular questions but the scores still weren't great so I wanted to see how it would be if multiple questions were taken out. I have 21 items using a likest-like scale 1-5.